# How do I stay alive in a dungeon?

Tags: terraria

I found a dungeon but , a dungeon guardian keeps killing me. My health lvl is 340 and my weapon is a light blood butcher. How can i explore the dungeon without it killing me.?

Comment: -1 for 0 research effort. Googling "terraria dungeon guardian" would have provided an instant answer to your question.

Comment: Seriously? The Old Man tells you to come backat night and free him from his curse before entering. I mean, OBVIOUSLY you need to kill Skeletron. *You should have figured that out a loooooonnnnnng time ago.*

Comment: *back at night :)

Answer (score 11):

You need to kill [Skeletron](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Skeletron) first (by talking to the old man above the dungeon at night). Otherwise the guardian spawns and insta-kills you.

Comment: Above the Dungeon? You mean the Dungeon entrance? *Be more specific.*

Comment: Lul, specific...

Answer (score 0):

The old man even tells you not to enter.

You have to kill Skeletron first. Talk to the old man. Don't fight till he says that you are powerful enough.

Comment: I mean, you've talked to him...RIGHT?!

Comment: That question is months old and already answered. Also, please don't post in all-caps.

Comment: Oh...didn't see that. =\

Comment: Edit = Helpful =)